# magento - where did theme-related files and folders inside includes/src come from?

Tags: magento

New to Magento here, please bear with me.

I installed a theme on Magento, which has these folders: `app`, `js`, `skin`, which is the usual. However, when I tried to uninstall the theme, I found that there files and folders for the theme have been created inside `includes/src` folder. Where did they come from, when the downloaded zip file of the theme didn't contain them?

I noticed this only happens to some themes installed. I know the files are related to the theme because the folder names inside `includes/src` are the developer and theme names.

Any ideas?

Magento (Enterprise 1.12)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you enable your compilation, Magento gets all the class and compiles them and puts them in `includes/src` directory. You can see all of your classes sitting there if you have your compilation on.

Check this in-depth details on Compilation by Alan Storm:
http://alanstorm.com/magento_compiler_path